# How can I select the arrow on image capture on mojave?

Tags: mojave

I usually [monosnap](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/monosnap-screenshot-editor/id540348655?mt=12) to add annotations (such as arrows etc) to screenshots. With the Mojave update, mac now has its own screen capture default tool.

I would like to use it, but I cannot select the arrow tool for some reason. How can I select it?

Also is there a tool to obscure sensitive areas in the screenshot?

finally what is this tool called? Once launched it doens't show an application name on the toolbar, and so I cannot find much references for it.

[image: how can]

Comment: How about letting the screen capture tool save the file on Desktop, open it with Preview? Preview has all the required tools.

Comment: Terrible idea.. i need a quick way to do this.. might as well just use monosnap

Comment: "finally what is this tool called?" It’s called "screencaptureui.app": `/System/Library/CoreServices/screencaptureui.app`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those arrow "formats" are tied to actual forms to be uses, not free-form lines created by the pen and marker tools.

If you add a form from the menu behind the square/circle icon and have it selected the arrow menu items become active (as a matter of fact the form menu already offers an arrow as a template).

[image: Step 1 - Select open form menu]
The yellow annotations are my "comments" here, the red ones are the results I added in a previous round of annotating. :)

[image: Step 2 - Add arrow format to a line]
Here I added a line first, now the arrow menu items are selectable. I chose one and the red line to the right turned into the arrow you see. You can also add an arrow directly from the form menu (not shown).

Oh, and btw, the added lines/arrows don't just have end points but also a middle "curving" point already, so it's easy to curve them.